# Set Title and SubTitle in CollapsingToolBar layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How to set title and sub title in collapsing toolbarlayout in Android like whatsapp profile view.

I have attached sample screen shot of the same.

[image: WhatsApp Profile view using collapsingtoolbar Layout]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally i get my answer. 
please check link. this is what i want.
https://github.com/harcoPro/SubtitleCoordinatorLayoutExample

[image]

Comment: @UmarulFarukh getting error: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to com.abc.xxx.HeaderView` on line `toolbarHeaderView = (HeaderView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_header_view);`.

Comment: @HammadNasir When is problem Started

Comment: @UmarulFarukh it is a `RuntimeException`. See: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.xxx/com.abc.xxx.Profile}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to com.abc.xxx.HeaderView`

Comment: @UmarulFarukh I have posted a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41492631/6144372 Please help with this!

Comment: I just made a similar library [collapsingtoolbarlayout-subtitle](https://github.com/HendraAnggrian/collapsingtoolbarlayout-subtitle), gradle-compatible. Would really love it if I could get someone to test it further because I haven't test it that much.

Comment: works but when collapsing the title and subtitle jumps into position--- i.e when expanded the left margin is 10 and when collapsed the left margin is about sixty and the text jumps into place rather than a nice animation