# android soft keyboard overlays the edittext in recyclerview in bottomsheet

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

I have a few `EditText` in `RecyclerView` that is inside of a `BottomSheetDialog`. The problem I have now is that when `BottomSheetDialog` is shown on the screen, I tap on for example the 7th  `EditText` in the `RecyclerView`. Soft keyboard appears and overlays the `EditText`, so I can't see what I type. but if I dragged the `BottomSheetDialog` a bit up, `EditText` then won't be covered by soft keyboard even if I tap on last `EditText` on the screen. `RecyclerView` is definitely resized in this case but doesn't resize if I didn't drag `BottonSheetDialog` a bit up. any idea why? and how I can fix this?

this is how it looks like. 
[image]

Main.java

```
class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public VH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

private void test() {
    BSTest bsTest = new BSTest(this);
    bsTest.setContentView(R.layout.bottomsheet_test);
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) bsTest.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rv.setAdapter(new RecyclerView.Adapter() {
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new VH(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_edittext, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 20;
        }
    });
    bsTest.show();
}
```

BSTest.java

```
public class BSTest extends BottomSheetDialog {
    public BSTest(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    private BSTest(@NonNull Context context, @StyleRes int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
    }

    private BSTest(@NonNull Context context, boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
    }
}
```

bottomsheet_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

item_edittext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show the screenshot

Comment: i added a short video

Comment: @user1865027 did you find out the problem/resolution to the problem?

Comment: @NitinMisra try with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288879/bottom-sheet-fragment-comes-up-with-keyboard (currently testing with it)

Comment: @NitinMisra try this for full screen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361569/set-title-and-subtitle-in-collapsingtoolbar-layout-android/33386325?noredirect=1#comment65103691_33386325

Answer (score 5):

Using this KeyboardUtil as new solution !

Use this in onCreateDialog in BottomSheetFragment

```
KeyboardUtil(getActivity(), view);
```

or

For fragment use

```
new KeyboardUtil(this, findViewById(R.id.fragment_container));
```

by using this Util class

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/aa9136fb4f5b3a80460fe5f47213985026d20c88/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/util/KeyboardUtil.java

Credit:Mikepenz

Answer (score 0):

It looks that editing your Manifest and adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to `<activity>` tag of this activity should solve your problem.

Docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: nah...doesnt work. and if `adjustResize` was the reason, why the first input didnt resize but 2nd input did.